# what is this kind of css animation?

Tags: html, css

In [this link](http://kangaroom.co.uk/flatshare/london),
There is a panel at the right hand side with class name **.list-panel**, the original width is 600px.

If you open the developer tools and change the width from 600px to ,say 900px and you will see there is a sliding effect. This is quite different from the normal behaviour.

How does it work actually? It looks like there is something monitoring the css style changes at all time and applies the changes with animation.

Thanks.

Comment: its a *CSS3* functionality called `transition`

Comment: How do I improve my question to make it acceptable? or stackoverflow only accepts questions with coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just your [average transition](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/), pretty cool:

```
.list-panel {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Good old CSS3 Animations, you got to love them!

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use `all` simply because it's harder to maintain if you want to change anything else. + it looks silly when you zoom in chrome. Also, `all` can be omitted, `transition: .5s ease;`.